# Subscribers Segmentation restrictions

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, sfmc-business-unit

I work with SFMC that has one central BU that manages other 10 different BU's. We have been dealing with an issue, for which one we haven't found one solution so far, and it is the following:
*when it comes to built a DE, one of the fields we use in Brand (is related with the different BU's in the company). What i'm trying to do is, by the time someone built an DE an goes to use this same field (Brand), i want that field to be restricted to specific BU's...For example i have BU1, BU2, BU3 and BU4. I'm on BU1 and if i would use BU2 on brand segment/field, that can't be done, because the manager used a restriction on brands to use.
Do you get my issue? It is possible to find a solution without change the General User permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing more context, I will recommend you either of these two options:

1. You should not allow access to the Enterprise BU to anyone but few admins, and all campaign operations should happen from within the specific child BUs. Brand specific data extensions shared between the enterprise BU and the respective child BUs should be filtered, so only records belonging to the brand relevant to that BU are included.

   As records from other brands will not be available to that BU, the risk of sending to the wrong audience will be largely reduced.
2. Another solution can be based on Ampscript in your email template, however this requires the *brand* field always to be included in your sendable data extension. You will be able to use [RaiseError](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/raiseerror.html) function to compare the *memberid* [personalisation string](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5) (identifying which BU is performing the send) with the *brand*, to stop the sendout in case the brand in the sendable data extension is not legitimate for the BU in question.